# Creating a lnk in VBS

Tags: vbscript, lnk

I get an error that on line 6, the one with lnk.TargetPath, that the argument is invalid. I am hoping to make a link to this program under the start menu on the desktop. Anybody know why it is doing this?

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\%USERDATA%\Desktop\Shutdown.LNK")
Dim strUserProfile
strUserProfile = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

lnk.TargetPath = "C:\Users\" & strUserProfile & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\shutdown.bat"
lnk.Arguments = ""
lnk.Description = "Shutdown"
'lnk.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
lnk.IconLocation = "C:\Users\" & strUserProfile & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\shutdown.bat, 2"
lnk.WindowStyle = "1"
lnk.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Users\" & strUserProfile &"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
lnk.Save
Set lnk = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because strUserProfiles holds the full path of user directory. Try this slightly modified code:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim strUserProfile
strUserProfile = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

Set lnk = objShell.CreateShortcut(strUserProfile & "\Desktop\Shutdown.LNK")

lnk.TargetPath = strUserProfile & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\shutdown.bat"
lnk.Arguments = ""
lnk.Description = "Shutdown"
'lnk.HotKey = "ALT+CTRL+F"
lnk.IconLocation = strUserProfile & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\shutdown.bat, 2"
lnk.WindowStyle = "1"
lnk.WorkingDirectory = strUserProfile &"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
lnk.Save
Set lnk = Nothing
```

Comment: Don't hard-code system paths. Use `objShell.`[`SpecialFolders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe(v=vs.84).aspx)`("Desktop")` and `.SpecialFolders("Programs")`.