# Cannot modify .LNK file using VBScript

Tags: .net, windows, vbscript, registry

I am trying to change arguments of shortcut, .LNK file. I have this code:

```
Set objFolder = fileSystem.GetFolder(folderPath)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colFiles
    If ( InStr(objFile.Name, ".lnk") ) Then

        Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(objFile.Name)
        Wscript.Echo oShellLink.TargetPath
        if ( InStr(oShellLink.TargetPath, "test.exe") ) Then
            UpdateShortcut(oShellLink)
        End If
    End If
Next

Function UpdateShortcut(shellLink)
    shellLink.Arguments = "-m Hello"
    shellLink.Save
    Wscript.Echo shellLink.Arguments
End Function
```

And I am getting really strange behavior. I have 2 shortcuts on Desktop named `Test.lnk` and `Test - Copy.lnk` and one in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. In order to modify the third one, I need write permissions, so I have this code at the start of my vbsript:

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If
```

Now, by running my vbscript, this command executes `Wscript.Echo shellLink.Arguments` three times and a three MessageBoxes popup saying "-m Hello", meaning `shellLink.Save` got executed with no errors. But none of link files get changed. However if I run without administrative rights, the two link files on the desktop get changed, but the third one does not.
Also, sometimes,  for some unknown reason I can't read `shellLink.TargetPath` property, which I need in order to figure out is this the right link/shortcut I need to edit.

My question is what am I doing wrong and is there any other (better) way of changing arguments in .LNK (shortcut) file? Also I should mention, I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Is virtualisation an issue?

Comment: How do you mean? I am running on physical computer, no virtual machines.

Comment: UAC causes Virtualisation. If you attempt to write to an admin only key/file it gets redirected elsewhere so your program thinks it worked (but it worked elsewhere to where you think). When running as admin that doesn't happen. To tell turn on the column Virtualisation in Task Manager's Detail tab (right click column headers on Win 10 - on earlier versions Process Tab and View menu).

Comment: I have just figured that, that is why Desktop shortcuts get changed when I am running w/o admin rights, since vbs file is on desktop. I should pass objFile.Path instead of objFile.Name to get it work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a lnk in VBS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006735/creating-a-lnk-in-vbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(objFile.Name)
```

creates/modifies shortcuts in the current working directory, so you're basically creating new shortcuts in a different location rather than modifying the existing ones.

Change this:

```
Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(objFile.Name)
```

into this:

```
Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(objFile.Path)
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: That's it, I have just figured that :D